# Write image in drawable using android 2.1

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a bitmap object. I want to overwrite a .png image under drawable folder with the bitmap object content. I need a sample code to do this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't overwrite resources in your application.

You can instead write to the internal memory or the sdcard.